# Conditional jump or move - Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm writing a program that reads commands from textfile and creates an adt based on them. When debugging with valgrind I get many errors saying that I am using unitialized variables. One of which looks like this

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5189==    at 0x4838DD0: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:512)
==5189==    by 0x109A28: reduce_space (in /home/jacob/CIS2500/Ass/Ass4/a4q2)
==5189==    by 0x10953A: main (in /home/jacob/CIS2500/Ass/Ass4/a4q2)
==5189==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5189==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==5189==    by 0x109925: reduce_space (in /home/jacob/CIS2500/Ass/Ass4/a4q2)
==5189==    by 0x10953A: main (in /home/jacob/CIS2500/Ass/Ass4/a4q2)
```

This error seems to be pointing to the reduce_space function:

```
char* reduce_space(char** string){
    char* input = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);
    char* new=malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);
    strcpy(input, *string);
    int space = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;


    while(input[i]!='\0'){
        if(input[i]==32){
            j=i+1;
            if(input[j]!='\0'){
                while(input[j]==32&&input[j]!='\0'){
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        new[count]=input[i];
        i++;
        count++;
    }
    new[i]='\0';
    strcpy(*string, new);
    free(input);
    free(new);
    return(*string);
}
```

I don't really understand where the uninitialised variable is. Am I declaring `input` and `new` wrong?

Example of how it's being called:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    int i;

    FILE* input = fopen("inputfile.input", "r");

    int max = file_size(input);
    char** command = malloc((sizeof(char*)) * max);

    for(i=0;i<max;i++){
        command[i] = malloc((sizeof(char))*BUFFER);
        fgets(command[i], BUFFER, input);
    }

    i = 0;
    while(command[i][0]!='\0'){
        reduce_space(&command[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What's in `inputfile.input`? What is `file_size()`? Please give some sample input that fails. For the sake of making a [mre], you could just hardcode `max`.

Comment: Do you include standard headers like `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`? Does your program compile without warnings? Is `"header.h"` relevant? It'll really help if you can give us a completely self-contained MRE that doesn't require us to do any editing or guessing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When `fgets()` reads strings it doesn't strip the trailing `\n` newlines. Every line from your file except perhaps the last one will have `\n` at the end, even the empty lines. Which means `command[i][0]!='\0'` won't detect them as empty and the loop will continue longer than it should.

Possible fixes:

- Check for both `\n` and `\0`.
- Strip newlines in the first `for` loop.
- Stop the loop if `i >= max`.
- Combine the two loops. You could call `reduce_space()` immediately after `fgets()` in the same loop.